# How to only modify a specific dictionary in a list

Tags: python

I want to only update a specific dictionary in a list if it meets a condition.
For example, if a value is equal to None then change that value.
Other things I have tried would affect all the dictionaries in the list, which is not what I'm trying to do.

```
clock = [{"date" : "07/09/2019", "clockIn" : 0500, "clockOut" : 0130}]
newtime = {"date" : "07/10/2019", "clockIn": 800, "clockOut": None}
clock.append(newtime)
print "first print", clock

for time in clock:
    print "second print" , time
    for k, y in time.values()
```

Comment: `clock[1]['clockOut'] = '1234'` ... would set only the second dictionary in your example  ...

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: use `if/else` to check which elements to copy from one dictionary to another.

Comment: @AnkushRasgon if the key has a value of None then modify that key's value to a number I would chose to give it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Anthony You could just loop over list and dictionary and change respective element conditionally.

```
clock = [{"date" : "07/09/2019", "clockIn" : "0500", "clockOut" : "0130"}]
newtime = {"date" : "07/10/2019", "clockIn": "800", "clockOut": None}
clock.append(newtime)
print ( "first print", clock)
print("\n")

for time in clock:    
    for item in time :                
       if time[item] is None:
          time[item] = "0000"

print ( "Second print", clock)
```

Output :

```
first print [{'date': '07/09/2019', 'clockIn': '0500', 'clockOut': '0130'}, {'date': 
'07/10/2019', 'clockIn': '800', 'clockOut': None}]


Second print [{'date': '07/09/2019', 'clockIn': '0500', 'clockOut': '0130'}, {'date': 
'07/10/2019', 'clockIn': '800', 'clockOut': '0000'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for time in clock:
    for i in time:
        if time[i] is None:
            time[i] = "changed"

print("second print", clock)
```

output:

```
first print [{'date': '07/09/2019', 'clockIn': 500, 'clockOut': 130}, {'date': '07/10/2019', 'clockIn': 800, 'clockOut': None}]

second print [{'date': '07/09/2019', 'clockIn': 500, 'clockOut': 130}, {'date': '07/10/2019', 'clockIn': 800, 'clockOut': 'changed'}]
```